# Gurobi c++: Getting constraint matrix

Tags: solver, gurobi, c++

I'm trying to get the constraint matrix from a Gurobi model in C++.
In Python, one can get this by simply calling a method that will populate a scipy object (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647230/get-constraints-in-matrix-format-from-gurobipy/40231779#40231779)). However, in a C++ fashion, one may expect three vectors (column, row, value) for the non-zero elements in the matrix.

One could technically iterate through the result of

```
GRBConstr* getConstrs() const;
```

however, I am not sure how efficient this method would be. Has anyone tried and found an efficient way of doing so?

EDIT:

One can also get the non-zero coefficients for a given variable  with

```
GRBColumn getCol(GRBVar v)
```

EDIT 2:
The first (possibly inefficient) idea is the following. Assume the object `presolved` stores the presolved model.

```
 auto         vars = presolved.getVars();
 //Getting the vars and iterating through them
 for (int v = 0; v < nVariables; ++v) {
 //Get the column of the v-th var
 auto varCol = presolved.getCol(vars[v]);
 

 if (varCol.size() > 0) { 
 //For any constraint in the number of constraints of the presolved model
    for (int c = 0; c < nconstr; ++c) {
      auto val = varCol.getCoeff(c);
      if (val > 1e-6 || val < -1e-6)
         // Fill the matrix A with the value
         A.at(c, v) = val;
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: If you have a large problem, you probably want to avoid dense matrices (I'm guessing `A` in `A.at[c, v]` is stored as a dense array). If you choose to work with a sparse matrix, I would expect the following to be decent: get the total number of non-zero coeffs, then populate a sparse column-wise matrix by iterating over the columns of the model.

Comment: @mtanneau Yes, that would be the idea. I also missed to say that the column should already haveonly non-zero coefficients. If that is true, the solution works. And no, not necessarily A is dense, but as of my example, the loop is iterating over every (possibly zero) value

Comment: Sorry to bring up this old question. Nonetheless, I think I answered your question [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/7915/3696).