# How to create A, b and c matrices from very large .lp file?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, modeling, gurobi, c++

I am working on Scaling MIP. I use Gurobi within Clion. I need to extract the coefficient of  Xs (A matrix), right-hand side (B matrix), and an objective function(c matrix) from the .lp file and create A,b,c matrices. Since my model includes more than 1000 constraints is not feasible to do it manually.

How can I create A,b,c matrices from the .lp file automatically?

Comment: Do you have access to the code that creates the .lp file? Because if so, depending on the solver you use, there are methods to help you get the coefficients you want. If the .lp file is the only thing you have, then maybe you should write a parser to read the file line by line and break it into an array.

Comment: I used Gurobi as a solver, added it to the question, I have only .lp file. I have seen some Gurobi methods like `GRBModel::getConstrs()` I hope I can handle it using them

Comment: If you have access to gurobi, it has methods like `Model.getA()` to give you the whole A matrix, and you can use `Model.getAttr()` with 'Obj' and 'RHS' to get matrices c and b, respectively. But if you don't have access to the code and you only have the .lp file, I'm not aware of any method other than writing a parser to read the text file for you and break it line by line and item by item (maybe using regex).

Comment: `model.getAttr()` and `model.getA()` does not seen by Gurobi(they are seen in red), is there any package I need to add  to make it work? So far I work on `model.getConstrs()`  and `model.getRow()` , I could not find what equalize `model.getConstrs()`. According to [Gurobi website](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/cpp_model_getconstrs.html) it requires a heap-allocated array but how to initilize/define and return that?

Comment: This is from gurobi on [`getA()`](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_geta.html). And this is for [`getAttr()`](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_getattr.html). You probably need to do something like: `model.getAttr('Obj', model.getVars())` or
`model.getAttr('RHS', model.getConstrs())`

Comment: When I wrote `model.getAttr('Obj', model.getVars())` will I make it equal to array since I have tried array and but it did not work. What to write on the left-hand side of this in the C++ program to retrieve the data? On the other hand,`getA()` is for Python, I looked for the in C++ API of Gurobi but could not find it. [link](https://www.gurobi.com/wp-content/plugins/hd_documentations/documentation/9.1/refman.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you linked to the documentation of the C++ API in the comments, I assume you are using C++. Typically, the constraint matrix A is sparse, so we use a sparse data structure. This requires significantly less storage compared to storing all matrix entries.

I will use the [Eigen::SparseMatrix](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html) class for this purpose, so you need to install the Eigen library. Nearly all decent C++ linear algebra libraries offer a similar sparse matrix class, so it shouldn't be hard to modify the following example.

You can use the following code snippet to read the coefficient matrix A, the right-hand side vector b and the objective coefficient vector c:

```cpp
/* read_lp.cpp */
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include "gurobi_c++.h"

using TripletVector = std::vector<Eigen::Triplet<double>>;
using SparseMatrix  = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>;
using Vector        = std::vector<double>;

std::tuple<SparseMatrix, Vector, Vector> read_Abc(GRBModel& model) {
    // number of variables, number of constraints, number of nonzeros in A
    std::size_t n       = model.get(GRB_IntAttr_NumVars);
    std::size_t m       = model.get(GRB_IntAttr_NumConstrs);
    std::size_t num_nnz = model.get(GRB_IntAttr_NumNZs);

    // allocate space
    TripletVector triplet(num_nnz);
    Vector b(m);
    Vector c(n);

    // Read the objective coefficients
    auto obj_expr = model.getObjective().getLinExpr();
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        c[j] = obj_expr.getCoeff(j);
    }

    // Read the coefficient matrix A and the rhs vector b
    std::size_t k = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        auto con      = model.getConstr(i);
        auto row      = model.getRow(con);
        for (std::size_t r = 0; r < row.size(); ++r) {
            auto col_idx = row.getVar(r).index();
            auto coeff   = row.getCoeff(r);
            triplet[k++] = Eigen::Triplet<double>(i, col_idx, coeff);
        }
        // read the constraint rhs
        b[i] = con.get(GRB_DoubleAttr_RHS);
    }

    // Construct the sparse matrix.
    SparseMatrix A(m, n);
    A.setFromTriplets(triplet.begin(), triplet.end());

    return {A, b, c};
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: read_lp filename" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    GRBEnv env     = GRBEnv();
    GRBModel model = GRBModel(env, argv[1]);

    auto [A, b, c] = read_Abc(model);

    // ... your code here. Use A.coeff(i, j) to access the element in row i
    // and column j inside the coefficient matrix A.
    std::cout << "rows: " << A.outerSize() << '\n';
    std::cout << "cols: " << A.innerSize() << '\n';
    std::cout << "nonzeros: " << A.nonZeros() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Besides including the gurobi headers and linking to the gurobi shared library, we only need to include the Eigen headers and compile with C++17. On macOS and Linux (please adapt the paths) this can look like this:

```bash
GUROBI_HOME="/Library/gurobi950/macos_universal2"
EIGEN_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.4.0_1"

clang++ read_lp.cpp -std=c++17 -Wall -I${EIGEN_HOME}/include/eigen3/ -I${GUROBI_HOME}/include/ -L${GUROBI_HOME}/lib -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi95 -o read_lp
```

Running and timing the above program with your example gives me:

```bash
 ↪  time ./read_lp Medium_Investment_Model.lp

Academic license - for non-commercial use only - expires 2022-02-28
Read LP format model from file Medium_Investment_Model.lp
Reading time = 0.48 seconds
: 190336 rows, 188505 columns, 419110 nonzeros

rows: 188505
cols: 190336
nonzeros: 419110

real    0m0.832s
user    0m0.740s
sys 0m0.078s
```

Comment: Thank you for the program, it worked on small lp files but on the large lp files I receive `Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)` error, I use Clion in Ubuntu 18.04, just to make sure can you please check following files with your program? I wonder whether they work in your computer correctly, [files link](https://github.com/mertsaner/LpFiles)

Comment: I use Clion and use `GRBModel model=GRBModel(env,"/home/username/CLionProjects/projectname/Small_Investment_Model.lp"); ` to run and make program read lp file. I use the header file for the method and then [use main.cpp to call the method.](https://github.com/mertsaner/LpFiles/blob/main/sandBoxExtra.h) When I use a terminal, I receive an error since GRBEnv is not defined there. You said "After compiling with C++17, execute the program and pass your .lp file as the first command-line argument." can explain debugging procedure a bit more? How do you run your C++ code with Gurobi in general?

Comment: How can I print A,b,c matrices?

Comment: A is an Eigen::SparseMatrix, so you can simply do `std::cout << A;` since the class overloaded the `<<`-operator. For `b` and `c` you simply iterate through the vectors and print the elements. Using Eigen::VectorXd instead of std::vector would allow you to do `std::cout << b;`.

Comment: As always, it's nearly impossible to help properly without a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Have a look at the [section *Iterating over the nonzero coefficients* in the docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html). If you then still have problems, I'd suggest asking a question at SO and providing an MWE.

Comment: `A.coeff(i,j) == 0.0` worked. I have realized later on that you have already wrote it as a comment in the code. I also would like to change`A[i][j] = A[i][j] * col_multi[j];`  but `A.coeff(i,j) = A.coeff(i,j) * row_multi[i];`  does not work and gives an error `error: expression is not assignable` What do you recommend?

Comment: `A.coeffRef(i, j) *= row_multi[i]` should work. However, please use SO to ask further C++ related questions. IMHO, it has nothing to do with the original question and goes beyond the scope of the comments section.

Comment: A short sub-question; How can I write a,b,c again to the model after manipulating them?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague - to implement a scaling method, you don't necessarily need the entire constraint matrix. Especially for equilibrium scaling (as noted here, in your [crosspost in the Gurobi Forum](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4460822390289-How-to-make-CLion-read-lp-file-and-make-Gurobi-solve-that-file-within-CLion-?page=1#community_comment_4469937109393)) you can just go through the rows and columns iteratively.

Comment: I think it is quite clear: How can I create A,b,c matrices from the .lp file automatically? If you know any simpler way for equilibrium scaling, feel free to share it

Comment: The thing is: if you have those matrices and vectors, and you have applied your scaling method, how do you get it back into the solver? Here, a constraint-wise approach might be better suited. Equilibrium scaling is dividing one row by the largest coefficient - this is independent of all other rows so you don't need access to all of them at the same time.

Comment: After I have applied scaling I will place scaled matrices again to the solver, and make it solve using scaled values. For row scaling, I need A and b and for column scaling, I need A and c, so I need A,b,c. Could you explain the constraint wise approach you mention?

Comment: Is there some kind of method/approach that I can reach and manipulate columns/rows without taking them out of the file?

Comment: Sure, you can use Model.getConstr(), Model.getRow(), row.getVar(), Model.getCoeff(), Model.setCoeff(). You have access to all the data of the model and can either manipulate it or create a new model. I strongly recommend Gurobi's Python interface for implementing this.

Comment: Since I am using C++ for the project, I need to proceed with that. Regarding Model.getConstr() and other functions, is there any guide to how to use them? For instance, what should I write in correspondence to Model.getConstr() = , is it return to Array, vector or...

Comment: You should consult the official Gurobi reference manual (https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/index.html) and the list of available examples to get started (https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/examples/index.html)

Comment: I have checked the reference manual in which it describes mode.getConstr(), but how can I retrieve those? So far, I have tried following but it did not work int `myArray [10000]={};
    myArray=model.getConstrs();`

Comment: It's completely infeasible to discuss such involved things in the comment section. You already got an excellent reply from @joni that demonstrates one way of working with the model data.